# Service privileges for Patch Download? (Oracle 11gR2)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, patch

To perform tests in advance of an upgrade from Oracle 11gR2 to 12c on our production systems, I tried to update the database of a developer virtual machine (Windows 7). The current Oracle Database version of this old developer machine is 11.2.0.1.0.
The setup file of Oracle 12c then told me to patch to 11.2.0.2, 11.2.0.3 or 11.2.0.4 first. So I tried to find and download the Patch to 11.2.0.4 for Windows x64. The [official Oracle page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) only lists 11.2.0.1, so I did a quick search that lead me to [this page](http://www.oradba.ch/2013/08/oracle-11-2-0-4-0-patchset-released/), which in turn lead me to [this page](https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/PatchDetails/process_form?patch_num=13390677).

I am used to be forced to login to download stuff from Oracle, but the second page tells me I need special support privileges. Seriously? Oracle allows me to setup a developing machine with their enterprise editions but I need support privileges to download a patch to the most recent version of Oracle 11?

Did I miss something? How am I supposed to test the upgrade process on my developing machine(s)?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: maybe more appropriate on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ . Good luck.

Comment: You need a support contract, yes. If your production DBs have support then your development DB may do too. You could ask your production DBAs for access to their CSI, or to supply the patchset/installer. But Oracle licensing is tricky so you (and they) need to be sure you're covered for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to know which "Customer Service Identifier" (CSI) you're using when you attempt to download the patch?

See if you can determine the "Customer User Administrator" (CUA) for your company's My Oracle Support (MOS) Account associated with that CSI.

Then send that party a request to grant you download privileges on that CSI.

You may encounter additional hurdles if the CSI in question has moved into "extended support required" status.

I had this very adventure a few months ago.

And note that though I am writing this in 2020 when Oracle 11g is out of support, my aim here is to help people work through the "not authorized to download" issue the question references - which can pertain to Oracle versions new and old.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to update your database version to version 12c.

Install the new version in a different HOME, export the full database 11g with `expdp` tool and then import it into the new updated data instance with `impdp` tool.